# Trouble Extracting Fitted Values with Year Information in Landtrendr using Javascript - 'index.toUpperCase' Error

Tags: google-earth-engine, time-series, landtrendr

I'm back working with Landtrendr in Javascript and have had some problems. I'm trying to separate the fitted row from the Landtrendr band and export it to an image, so I have year bands of fitted values for my area of interest.

I select the Landtrendr 4xn band and slide in the matrix's row to obtain the fitted values. I also need each band to contain the year of the observation.

However, I get the error: "In users/emaprlab/public:Modules/LandTrendr.js
index.toUpperCase is not a function". Do you know what could be causing the error or how else I can extract this data?

```
// load the LandTrendr.js module
var ltgee = require('users/emaprlab/public:Modules/LandTrendr.js');

// define parameters
var startYear = 1990;
var endYear = 2010;
var startDay = '01-01'; //month - day   // '11-15'       '01-31'                                                                                              //    ! ! ! !
var endDay = '03-31';                   // '12-31'      '03-31'
var coords = [[-71.3168,-33.9135], 
              [-71.3095,-33.9135],
              [-71.3095,-33.9096],
              [-71.3168,-33.9096],
              [-71.3168,-33.9135]];
var aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(coords);
var bandList = ['NDVI'];
var index = ['NDVI'];
var ftvList = [];
var  maskThese = ['cloud','shadow','snow','water']

Map.addLayer(aoi, {}, "polygon");
Map.centerObject(aoi, 12);

var run_params = { 
  maxSegments:            6,
  spikeThreshold:         0.9,
  vertexCountOvershoot:   3,
  preventOneYearRecovery: true,
  recoveryThreshold:      0.25,
  pvalThreshold:          0.05,
  bestModelProportion:    0.75,
  minObservationsNeeded:  6
};

// run landtrendr
var lt = ltgee.runLT(startYear, endYear, startDay, endDay, aoi, index, ftvList, run_params, maskThese);
var LTresult = ee.Algorithms.TemporalSegmentation.LandTrendr(run_params); // run LT-GEE

var LTarray = LTresult.select(['LandTrendr']); // subset the LandTrendr segmentation info
//var year = LTarray.arraySlice(0, 0, 1); // slice out the year row
var fitted = LTarray.arraySlice(0, 2, 3); // slice out the fitted values row

var fitted = fitted.arrayProject([1]);

var years = [];                                                           // make an empty array to hold year band names
for (var i = startYear; i <= endYear; ++i) years.push('yr'+i.toString()); // fill the array with years from the startYear to the endYear and convert them to string
var fittedStack = fitted.arrayFlatten([years]);                             // flatten this out into bands, assigning the year as the band name
print(fittedStack, 'fitted stack');
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/794aa2b0d980ccae7a1a96e90e3b6673

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because `ltgee.runLT` is [expecting a string](https://emapr.github.io/LT-GEE/api.html#runlt) `index` and you're passing an array of one string. The error message gives you a hint that `index.toUpperCase` is getting called, which would only make sense if `index` was a string.

Using `var index = "NDVI"` instead of `var index = ["NDVI"]` should solve the problem.